# Span class nav-header can't be found

Tags: joomla-3.x

All menu items have class "item-text". 
But one Menu Heading has class "nav-header". 
I searched "nav-header" class in each css file, but could not find.
I need that class to make the font-size larger.
Where can I find it?

Comment: `nav-header` may be coming from the Joomla core, but it's possible that your template doesn't use it. Can you not simply use another selector to target in the CSS?

Comment: @Lodder, I ve solved it. I found that css with web developer extension for Mozilla. Yes, it comes from Joomla core. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and make it as "accepted", below ,else close the question

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I found that css style with web developer extension for Mozilla. It comes from Joomla core.